# why only first letter is returned by match function?

Tags: javascript, regex

If metacharacter `?` matches the preceding element zero or one time, then

why

```
"ab".match(/a?/)
```

returns `["a"]`,

but

```
"ab".match(/b?/)
```

returns `[""]`

?

Comment: Then why not [""] is returned in first case?

Comment: (If somebody ask: why not?)

Comment: `?` is greedy, so it will match as much as possible in the position it's at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if I can explain it better with the following analogy.

Imagine a friendly fast food cashier, a queue of hungry customers and a kind of conveyor belt full with burgers. She offers the burgers one by one to each customer until all of them are happy (if some burgers are left, it doesn't matter). Then she writes down the list of what each customer has got and gives this list to her manager.  Cashier will be the regex engine, burgers are symbols from the input string and customers are regex subexpressions. Manager is the match function.

For example when matching `abbc` against `/[a]b+./`, the scene plays like this:

```
("[a]", "b+" and "." stand the queue)

Cashier: Hi, "[a]", would you like "a"?
[a]: Sure, thanks!
C: would you also like "b"?
[a]: No, thanks, I'm fine (goes).
C: Hi, "b+", would you like "b"?
b+: Sure.
C: Would you like another "b"?
b+: Yes, I'm hungry.
C: Can I offer you "c" also?
b+: Not my kind of thing (goes).
C: Hi, ".", I have only one "c" left.
.: I don't care what it is, just gimme it (goes).
C: All served! Looks like I'll get the job!
```

If it happens that the cashier is unable to satisfy a customer, she has a right to call the previous one and ask them to give back what they've got. This is called "backtracking". Consider:

```
 "abx" against /.+[xyz]/

 C: Hi, ".+", would you like "a"?
 .+: Yum-yum!
 C: How about "b"?
 .+: Yum-yum!
 C: And "x"?
 .+: Yum-yum!
 C: My belt is empty! (.+ goes)
 C: Hi, "[xyz]", I'm afraid I'm sold out. 
 [xyz]: That's out of the question. Can I see the manager?
 C: Wait, I think we can sort it out! (calls ".+")
 C (to ".+"): Sorry pal, you know, this nasty guy over there... 
              I wonder if you could you give me back your last one?
 .+: No prob... (gives "x" back)
 C (to "[xyz]"): I've got something for you. Do you eat "x"?
 [xyz]: If you want to get anything done in this country 
        you've got to complain until you are blue in the mouth 
        (gets his "x" and goes in a rage)
 C: Gosh, what a day...
```

Now back to your examples:

```
Scene I. "ab" against /a?/ 
Burgers: a and b, customer: a?

C: Hi, "a?" would you like "a"?
a?: Sure, thanks.
C: Can I offer you "b" also?
a?: No, thanks, I'm fine (goes).
Manager: I need the inventory report, now!
C: Here you go: "a?" got "a", we have "b" and "c" left.

Scene II. "ab" against /b?/ 
Burgers: a and b, customer: b?

C: Hi, "b?" would you like "a"?
b?: No thanks, but that's no problem. (goes).
M: Status?
C: "b?" got nothing and went. a, b, c are still there.
```

So, basically `b?` is a very nice (and not particularly hungry) guy, and he's happy even if the cashier has nothing for him. If he's the only one in the queue, it's her lucky day!

Comment: Imagine the most happy scene (for customer, cashier and particularly manager): "" against /.*/

Comment: @user3119308: ;)) Every analogy is just an analogy. Don't take it too seriously!

Comment: @user3119308: I don't think that's happy. The shop sells nothing, and even if it did there is an infinitely hungry customer who blocks everything…

Answer (score 8):

Because that's the first match. The regex tries at first to match at position 0, where regex#1 does match an `a` and regex#2 does match the empty string. Then it attempts to match at position 1, where regex#1 does match the empty string and regex#2 does match the letter `b`. At last, it tries to match at position 3, where both regexes match the empty string.

Compare the returned matches with a global flag:

```
> "ab".match(/a?/)
["a"]
> "ab".match(/a?/g)
["a", "", ""]
> "ab".match(/b?/)
[""]
> "ab".match(/b?/g)
["", "b", ""]
```

> why not [""] is returned in first case?

Due to the mechanisms of [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). When attempting to match at some position, the engine will try to greedily<sup>1</sup> test all letters of the regex against the letters of the string. When it reaches the end of the regex with that method, a match succeeded. When a letter doesn't fit in, it tries to go back in the regex to see whether any omissions can be made - when using modifiers such as `*` or `?` - or alternatives (`|`) need to be considered, and then continues from there.

Example: Match `/b?/` at position 0 of `"ab"`:

```
//   - "": ✓
/b/  - "a": ×
/b?/ - "": ✓ - succeed (end of regex)
  ^ means here that the "b" token is omitted
```

Example: Match `/a?/` at position 0 of `"ab"`:

```
//  - "": ✓
/a/ - "a": ✓ - succeed (end of regex)
```

Example: Match `/ab?(bc)?/` at position 0 of `"abc"`

```
//        - "": ✓
/a/       - "a": ✓
/ab/      - "ab": ✓
/ab(b)/   - "abc": ×
/ab(bc)?/ - "ab": ✓ - succeed (end of regex)
```

<sub>1: Usually, at least. Many regex flavours also provide quantifiers that are [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) or [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) if you want to control the exact matching behaviour. For example, `/ab??(bc)?/` matches `abc` in `"abc"`</sub>

Comment: +1 but "position 0" doesn't seem really clear for me. Especially when you consider `"".match(/a?/g)`. It looks to me like half the answer.

Comment: "position 0" is the string beginning, i.e. left to the `a` in `"ab"`. You're right, empty matches are confusing :-)